# How to Get Position of Specific Shape In Image c#

Tags: image, c#-4.0, shapes

I Have many Image That they are Exam Question Papers . the number of question in each papers are different, for example one of them is English exam that has 12 questions and other is Math Exam with 5 questions. i want to crop image and get each question in paper separately. For Crop Image  i use Aspose dll. aspose wants the begin and end position to crop the image. how can i detect each question start and end, for this i think i must use specific shape at the end of question and detect the shape position bu i cant find the solution to get position of shape
2 important note :
1. i want it automatically, it means the end user scan the file i detect each question and then crop it(i use the manual way that the end user enter the positions and its works but i dont want it)
2. i use afrog dll that detect his own shape but when add shape it couldnt detect the shape

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Imaging is an image processing API that lets developers create, edit, draw or convert images in applications. Aspose.Imaging does not support the functionality to detect start/end point of any shape in an image.

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.